# Aligning h1 with navigation bar

Tags: css

Server side developer here, trying to teach myself some styling.

I was trying to replicate the header section (`id=topbar`) from [this site](http://www.hanselman.com/). My initial efforts have failed to align the `h1` (scott hanselman) with the navigation list items (about , blog etc) - I was mostly experimenting with `float: left` and `display: inline` to overcome the block nature of the `h1` - I failed!

On playing with the CSS in the chrome dev tools, I've not understood how he has aligned those items nicely in `containerInner`. I've found when I toggle the inherited `margin` property (line 4-9 of the css) the nav items fall below the `h1` as I would expect as a block element.

My question is, what is making the `h1` not take all available horizontal space? Seems like my guess of `float` and `display` properties missed the mark.

Here is my efforts thus far:
HTML

```
<!doctype html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>first last</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="blog_style.css" type="text/css" />
</head>

<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="top-ribbon-outer">
            <div class="top-ribbon-inner">
                <h1>first last</h1>
                <nav>
                    <ul>
                        <li>item1</li>
                        <li>item2</li>
                        <li>item3</li>
                        <li>item4</li>
                    </ul>
                </nav>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

CSS:

```
body {
    font-family: "Open Sans", "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 15px;
    margin-left: 50px;
}

.top-ribbon-outer {
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
    color: white;
    background-color: black;
    position: relative;
}

.top-ribbon-inner {
    height: 20px;
}

h1 { 
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    margin-top: 0px;
    float: left;
    /*display: inline;*/
}

li { 
    float: left;
    padding-left: 15px;
    padding-right: 15px;
}

ul {
    list-style-type: none;
}
```

Comment: Do you have this live somewhere?

Comment: @NikolaR. No, just developing locally. Save the html as a file and the css as `blog_style.css` in the same directory and that should work for you.

Comment: Updated my answer, take css and you can play with font-size.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `display:inline-block` for `ul` and `h1` header. So try this

```
h1 { 
    margin-left: 10px;
    margin-top: 10px;
    float: left;
    display: inline-block;
}

ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    display:inline-block;
    float:right;
}
```

[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RUtu5/)

Comment: Hi, thanks for the solution, looks good! Were you able to identify how it was achieved on the referenced site? Would like to plug the gap in my understanding.

Comment: @markdsievers on the referenced site, they also used the same concept like float `h1` in the left and `nav` to the rigth and used `dispaly:block`

Answer (score 0):

No need for setting parent's height. Just use `overflow: hidden` and it will correctly cover it's floating children

CSS:

```
body {
    font-family: "Open Sans", "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 15px;
    margin-left: 50px;
}

.top-ribbon-outer {
    width: 100%;
    color: white;
    background-color: black;
    position: relative;
}

.top-ribbon-inner {
    overflow: hidden;
}

h1 { 
    margin: 0;
    float: left;
    padding: 5px;
}
nav {
 float: right;
}

li { 
    float: left;
    padding-left: 15px;
    padding-right: 15px;
}

ul {
    list-style-type: none;
}
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/8wY8B/)**